# Google foo.bar Challenge Issue: Can't import libraries

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on a problem (doomsday_fuel) using python and I need to use matrices, so I would like to import numpy. I have solved the problem and it runs perfectly on my own computer, but Google returns the error: **ImportError: No module named numpy [line 3].**

The beginning of my code looks like:

`import fractions
from fractions import Fraction
import numpy as np`

I have checked constraints.txt and they do not seem to restrict numpy

"Your code will run inside a Python 2.7.6 sandbox. Standard libraries are supported except for bz2, crypt, fcntl, mmap, pwd, pyexpat, select, signal, termios, thread, time, unicodedata, zipimport, zlib."

Does anyone have any ideas how or why this would happen? Or do people have ideas as to what steps I could take to ask Google about this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the project structure you're using - but have you installed numpy? Was it ever installed with the `pip install` command? Does your project have a requirements.txt file in it?

Comment: Do they really expect us to invert a 4x4 or 5x5 matrix without numpy or sympy....?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately numpy is not a standard library in python 2.7, and is not supported by foobar.  For a complete list of available modules, I suggest looking here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/

Answer (score 4):

Math is a standard library but still it is not working with the Foobar.

Comment: It is. You're probably using functions (e.g. `math.gcd`) that were not available in Python 2.7.